# Not able to make button text capital using : android:textAllCaps="true" in custom button class extending button class

Tags: android, button, capitalization

I am using CustomButton class to apply font to button text, But simultaneously,I want to make the button text upper case. I used   android:textAllCaps="true" , But this was not effecting anything.

```
 <shiva.joshi.common.customs.CustomButton

                    style="@style/login_option_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_green_height"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_green_background"
                    android:text="@string/registration"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    />
```

Please help me to resolve this bug.

Comment: Do you always want this type of button to be allcaps? Or just in this one usage?

Comment: inside your style "login_option_button" are you overrided attribute "textAllCaps" or in parent style?

Comment: @billynomates , I want just in this usage.

Comment: @an_droid_dev I tried but not working.

Comment: @Er.Joshi look also inside folde V21 there inside your xml style. Can you post here both files?